# Use of curve_fit to fit data of 2 variables in a list

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am kind of new to scipy and `curve_fit`.

I have 2 lists:

x values:

```
[0.723938224, 0.965250965, 1.206563707, 1.447876448, 1.689189189, 
1.930501931, 2.171814672]
```

y values:

```
[2.758, 2.443, 2.142333333, 1.911, 1.817666667, 1.688333333, 1.616]
```

I would like to perform a `curve_fit` on these 2 datasets, but I cannot seem to figure out the relationship. I known roughly the equation that fits them both together:

I know that there' an equation that fits them together:

```
0.74/((9.81*(x/100))^(1/2))
```

But how would I prove that the equation is the equation above just using python curve fits. If I do a similar thing in excel, it would automatically give me the equation. How would it work in python?

I am not sure how to perform the `curve_fit` and draw the trendline. Could someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the examples at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html ? What did you try to make it work with your example? What didn't work and what problems did you have?

Comment: Yes I did take a look. However, there was no reference to 2 different lists and use of the equation. Sorry, I am still new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, let's define the curve fit function. You say that Excel tells you the function is of the form `a/(b*(x/c)**d)`. I tell you, Excel knows nothing about anything apart from autofill; this equation can easily be transformed into `((a*c**d)/b)/x**d`, so the function we actually have to consider is of the form `a/x**b`.
Now to the actual [curve fitting with scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [0.723938224, 0.965250965, 1.206563707, 1.447876448, 1.689189189, 1.930501931, 2.171814672]
y = [2.758, 2.443, 2.142333333, 1.911, 1.817666667, 1.688333333, 1.616]

def func(x, a, b):
    return a/(x**b)

#start values, not really necessary here but good to know the concept
p0 = [2, 0.5]
#the actual curve fitting, returns the parameters in popt and the covariance matrix in pcov
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y), p0)
#print out the parameters a, b
print(*popt)
#a=2.357411406488454, b=0.5027391574181408

#plot the function to see, if the fit is any good
#first the raw data
plt.scatter(x, y, marker="x", color="red", label="raw data")
#then the fitted curve
x_fit = np.linspace(0.9*min(x), 1.1*max(x), 1000)
y_fit = func(x_fit, *popt)
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, color="blue", label="fitted data")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Looks good to me. And one shouldn't let Excel near any statistical data, if you asked me.

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification. This really helped. The equation on Excel did confuse me slightly but now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: I had a small other question. When I calculated the standard deviation of this data set: error = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)), I got 2 values for standard deviation in an array. What do these mean? And how would I plot appropriate error bars for this?

Comment: Imho the covariance matrix reflects the standard error of the determined variables (here, a and b) and their dependence (in the fields that are not the diagonal). Had we chosen the initial equation with a, b, c, and d, this matrix would have told us that a, b, and c are not independent, but d is. Not sure though, how to interpret the SD of the estimated parameters (it it not the confidence interval or similar, if you thought it is). I suggest asking this statistical question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: So you say we are getting a standard deviation for the values of a and b?

Comment: Yes. Try it. Re-define the function as `a/(c*x**b)` and observe how the covariance matrix changes, especially for the relationship `a` with `c`. [Here is a good explanation of the covariance matrix.](https://datascienceplus.com/understanding-the-covariance-matrix/)